# Is there a Linq method to 'extend' collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder if there is a Linq method to simply enumerate over another collection after the current one? If not, why not?

To highlight exactly what I mean, imagine we had:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 1, 5, 6 };
```

then I am asking if there is a Linq method such that `a.MyHypotheticalExtensionMethod(b)` would produce the IEnumerable containing: `{1,2,3,1,5,6}`

Of course, its trivial to roll one's own (or even to just work around) but it definately seems like something that ought to be included in Linq?

Comment: _[LINQ 101](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)_ has always been a great first port-of-call.  In this case [Concat](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Miscellaneous-6b72bb2a#Concat1)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes? I didn't know Concat existed. I tried googling for what i was looking for but couldn't find it so asked a question. I couldnt find a duplicate and feel I worded a specific question in a clear way? Why the downvotes?

Comment: Generally questions should show signs of research; even then I like to give the author a chance to fix before down voting. Wasn't me in this case. Consider revising your question to include what you just said about research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `a.Concat(b)`.